# Copy files from one remote server to another remote server with Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to copy files from serverA to serverB using Powershell. Both servers belong to our hosting provider so copying files from A to B is very fast compared to copying files from my local box to either server.
I figured I could use Powershell to run a remote command on serverA and copy the files to serverB. This is what I came up with:

```
$SourceServerName = "serverA"
$SourceContentPath = "\\serverA\c$\testSrc"
$DestinationContentPath = "\\serverB\c$\testDest"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SourceServerName -ScriptBlock {param ($SourcePath,$InstallPath) 
                Copy-Item -Path $SourcePath\* -Destination $InstallPath -Recurse
            } -ArgumentList $SourceContentPath, $DestinationContentPath
```

But I get an error "System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Access to the path 'testDest' is denied.

I'm an admin and WinRM is configured properly on both boxes. If I try to copy files remotely inside the same server (i.e. from \\serverA\c$\testSrc to \\serverA\c$\testDest) everything works fine.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: The account which runs powershell should be admin of both boxes. You should also check that c:\testDest on serverB has good permissions for the account you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke-Command` is executed under your current user (user you are currently logged into your machine). You should set `-Credential` parameter of your `Invoke-Command` to the admin user of target system

Answer (score 0):

The cmdlet on Server A is not executed as you.

Two possible solutions:

#### Easiest:

```
$SourceServerName = "serverA"
$SourceContentPath = "\\serverA\c$\testSrc"
$DestinationContentPath = "\\serverB\c$\testDest"
$cred = Get-Credential # input your username and password of serverB here

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SourceServerName -ScriptBlock {param ($SourcePath,$InstallPath, $cred) 
            Copy-Item -Path $SourcePath\* -Destination $InstallPath -Recurse -Credential $cred
        } -ArgumentList $SourceContentPath, $DestinationContentPath, $cred
```

#### Domain User Solution:

If you are a domain user, and could control these two machines you could just enable CredSSP in PowerShell via `Enable-WSManCredSSP` on both your local computer and serverA, then add the `-Authentication CredSSP` in `Invoke-Command`.